# Loading CSS and JavaScript with with bottle.py

Tags: javascript, python, css, bottle

I am trying to write an app with [Bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My view copies these import statements without actually importing the css + js files themselves.

I have included a `static` template, as the [tutorial](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#routing-static-files) suggests

```
@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/static/')
```

How do I modify the HTML so my browser reads the `*.js , *.css` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used (as an example)

```
... href="/arch/favicon.ico"
```

and I have

```
@route('/arch/<filename>')
def fileget(filename):
```

for static files.

Answer (score 0):

Using `:path` filter allow match such URLs like `/bootstrap.min.js` or `/js/bootstrap.min.js`. In the first case Bottle returns file `/usr/home/project/client/bootstrap.min.js`, in second `/usr/home/project/client/js/bootstrap.min.js`.

```
@route('<path:path>')
def server_static(path):
    return static_file(path, root='/usr/home/project/client')
```

> :path matches all characters including the slash character in a non-greedy way and can be used to match more than one path segment.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex matching to serve `.css` & `.js` files:

```
@route('/<file:re:.*\.(css|js)>')
def serve_cssjs_suffixed_file(file):
    return static_file(file)
```

Some of notable options to the 'static_file' function are:

`root='target_dir'` point to directory containing the files

`mimetype='text/css'` manually pass MIME type if bottle guessed incorrectly